# serialize and unserialize in sessions

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get multiple values in session and show products in my checkout page. My problem is that the id that stores in session is only one (last selected product)

**ajax.page**

```
$cartArray = unserialize($_SESSION[['cart']]);//convert text to array (because $_session['cart'] is text)
$cartArray [] = $_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($cartArray);//convert array to text (store)
```

**checkout page**

i want just for test that insert index 2

```
<?php
$idCart = unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
$query = "select * from products where id=".$idCart[2];
$sel = $db->select($query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
$image = $result['image'];
$name = $result['name'];
$price = $result['price'];
?>
```

Comment: I see extra `[]` in `$_SESSION[['cart']]`

Comment: Explain More it's unclear what you're asking !